# C# Regex - endless matching

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to use Regex to get data from repeated XML tag:

```
<A>cat</A><A>dog</A>
```

So I've created Regex:

```
<A>(.*?)</A>
```

and code:

```
string text = "<A>asdasd</A><A>dsfsd</A>";
string regex = @"<A>(.*?)</A>";

Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);
Match match = rgx.Match(text);
while(match.Success)
{
     i++;
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
     match.NextMatch();
}
```

But when I start my code, my loop is endless and never stop.

Can someone help me find what's wrong with code? Or find another solution?
(I don't want to deserialize XML).

Comment: Regex are not the best approach to match xml. I suggest you to use [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) or [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
match.NextMatch();
```

just returns the next match, it doesn't change the state of `match` itself.  You need to update the variable:

```
match = match.NextMatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

While the failure reason is that you did not assign the next match to `match`, you can actually use `Regex.Matches` to get all the substrings you need in one go without the need for an explicit loop:

```
var results = rgx.Matches(text)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

See the [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/liqb9G):

```
var text = "<A>asdasd</A><A>dsfsd</A>";
var regex = @"<A>(.*?)</A>";
var rgx = new Regex(regex);
var results = rgx.Matches(text)
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));  
// asdasd
// dsfsd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use **Regex.Matches** to load them all into a collection, and proceed to iterate it.

```
string text = "<A>asdasd</A><A>dsfsd</A>";
string regex = @"<A>(.*?)</A>";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, regex))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Or single line using Linq:

```
Regex.Matches(text, regex).Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value));
```